# Change List Item Color When Checkbox is Selected in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, contact-form-7

I've been wracking my brain about this problem for a few days now. I'm working on a wordpress site that uses Contact Form 7 (CF7). Basically, I'm trying to change have each list item change color when the checkbox is selected.

This topic has been my main inspiration so far: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/on-click-of-check-box-my-div-border-and-text-color-should-be-in-blue/276230/3

But I'm unsure of how to get the code to work within the CF7 editor (I've tried the support forums in that plugin, but no one answered me there haha).

Relevant code in CF7:

```
<span onclick="UpdateFeatures(this,false);"> [checkbox* InterestsAndGoals id:getStartedInterestsAndGoals use_label_element "Growth" "Marketing Exposure" "Increase in overall traffic" "Edge over your competition" "Increase in low season traffic"]</span>
```

Javascript used in CF7:

```
<script>
function UpdateFeatures(checkbox) {
  console.log(document.querySelector(".wpcf7-list-item"));
  document.querySelector(".wpcf7-list-item").classList.remove("changeColor");
  if (checkbox.checked) {
  document.querySelector(".wpcf7-list-item").classList.add("changeColor");
  }
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#getStartedInterestsAndGoals input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

span.wpcf7-list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.wpcf7-list-item {
  margin: 0 0 20px 1em;
  border: 1px solid #f26922;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wpcf7-list-item:hover {
  background-color: #f26922;
  border-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.changeColor {
  background-color: #f26922;
  border-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

JSFiddle to demonstrate code made from CF7:
https://jsfiddle.net/p9wrdsmo/1/

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I'm not very good at JavaScript and would have preferred pure HTML/CSS, but I don't believe it's possible.

Thank you!!